# Is nestjs interceptor only available for @Get?

Tags: nestjs

```
@Injectable()
export class TransformInterceptor<T> implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>> {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<Response<T>> {
    return next.handle().pipe(map(data => {
      // console.log('data', data) response result
      return {result: data};
    }));
  }
}
```

In @Get, i can see the response result

But in the case of @Post, the data is not visible. Why?

Comment: Interceptors absolutely work on POST requests as well. Can you show the controller code and how you bind the interceptor to the application?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel It was my mistake, I checked the documentation again, thank you